# Display output from a method on a JPanel in Java

Tags: java, swing

I have a GUI the gets an input from a text area and on the click of button produces a report. The report is supposed to be displayed below the input area. On the click of the button, the input data are passed to a a void method called Calculate(), and right now the correct results are displayed on the console by System.out.printf(). How can I redirect this output to the report area?

```
public class Progress extends JFrame
{
   JTextArea input;
   JButton calculate;
   JPanel report;

   public void Notify()
     {
         calculate = new JButton("Calculate");
        calculate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Calculate();
            }
        });
     }
}

...

public void Calculate()
    {
        GenerateReport m = new GenerateReport();
        m.Parsecsv(input.getText());

    }
```

So, as a newbie to Java, I wanted to know how I can redirect the output of my Calculate() method to the report panel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you could modify your Calculate to return a string containing the information you want to print into the text area. I assume you know how to make simple methods that aren't void and return a data type:

```
public String Calculate() { 
    <something to get the text needed is done here>
    return <text from report>;
}
```

Then you could make a "JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( Calculate() )" to show the report, or you could as mentioned create a JLabel to print the report within the frame your working with.

Something like:

```
JLabel lab1 = new JLabel(null, Calculate() );
```

If I understand you right?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're trying to ask is, "What is a JLabel?". You can use a JLabel to output your text from your calculate method. 
Or you can return a String from your calculate method and somehow display it otherwise.

Comment: The problem is not JLabel. I can create a string return for my method, but my problem is that how that returned string can be directed to be displayed on the report JPanel?

Comment: @user843681 It can be displayed using a `JLabel` or a `JTextField` or a `JTextArea` or in `JOptionPane` or via custom painting.  You question is woefully vague and shows little to no effort on your part to actually research the problem.  I'd start by taking a look at [creating a GUI with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)

Comment: I have been researching for a quite a long time. The solution out there are mostly incorrect.

Comment: @user843681: `"the solution out there are mostly incorrect"` -- what the flip? Without a specific question, your question is "mostly incorrect". And how do you know that they are "incorrect" when you yourself state that you're a newbie to Java?